# The underlying provider failed on Open, WCF Service with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wcf

Our application has a triple set up of servers(Web, App, DB). Web tier consists of the UI and app layer consists of the services. Each has their own dedicated server. Recently our client asked for migration of the DB server to 2016 (Its in 2008 now). So i have taken a DB backup from 2008 and restored in the 2016 DB server. Then i configured the app layer services(WCF & WebServices) to point the 2016 DB. Now i couldnt login. and i checked the services using WCF test client and i got the following error

> The underlying provider failed on Open. FULL EXCEPTION: System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[System.ServiceModel.ExceptionDetail]: The underlying provider failed on Open. (Fault Detail is equal to An ExceptionDetail, likely created by IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults=true

Detailed Inner Exception Message:

Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding. at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj) at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadSniError(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, UInt32 error) at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInterna...).  System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message) Exception rethrown at [0]: at 
System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg) at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type) at client.services.SSO.validatesptoken()..

And sometimes i get this inner exception error msg too

Test ERROR MESSAGE:Execution of the command requires an open and available connection. The connection's current state is broken. FULL EXCEPTION: System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[System.ServiceModel.ExceptionDetail]: Execution of the command requires an open and available connection. The connection's current state is broken. (Fault Detail is equal to An ExceptionDetail, likely created by IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults=true, whose value is: System.InvalidOperationException: Execution of the command requires an open and available connection. The connection's current state is broken. at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.EnsureConnection() at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption) at

But this error only comes for the services using entity framework, the other web services are working fine. 
I will post the EF connection string too

```
<add
      name="SSOObjectContext" connectionString="metadata=res://*/SSOModel.csdl|res://*/SSOModel.ssdl|res://*/SSOModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=myDBServer;initial catalog=***;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=***;Password=***;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;"
      providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

This has nothing to do with the user privileges or connection strings as i have tried and modified using the answers but could not find any luck. this turning out to be a thorn as any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You haven't provided any code or the actual exception. You should add exception handling to your service and log the full exception text, the way it's returned by `Exception.ToString()`. This contains any inner exceptions, the call stack that caused the exception and points to the source code line that raised the exception. It's the *inner* exceptions that contain the actual reason for the failure

Comment: It could be that the server isn't running. It could be that the login is wrong, or that this user doesn't have permission to connect to that database. The *database* name may be missing, in which case the connection will be made to the user's default database.

Comment: In fact, where's the database name in the connection string??

Comment: Added the inner exception too... It clearly seems the connection itself not getting established. the connection string is fine. i have just provided the exact conn string we are using. please have a look at it

Comment: You still haven't posted any code. Although the exception suggests there was a timeout while executing a query. This doesn't seem to have anything to do with WCF. Without the code, one can only suggest searching for the error message `Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding`. There are a *lot* of similar questions in SO. The problem could be due to an inefficient query that exceeds the 60 seconds which is the default timeout, or the query is loading a lot of data that takes more than 60 secs. Or a Slow server

Comment: There may be missing indexes that force a full table scan on a slow server. Or the query is so complicated that the database server produces a bad execution plan. Try capturing the database queries with SQL Server Profiler or better yet, [Extended Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/extended-events/extended-events?view=sql-server-2017). SQL Server 2016's [Query Store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/monitoring-performance-by-using-the-query-store?view=sql-server-2017) can be used to monitor performance too and detect

Comment: Thank you Panagiotis Kanavos. i will try the options